# Define path for unknown folder path using * asterisk

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to define a file path where the folder name is unknown

I have already tried * asterisk to define the unknown folder, but it's not working.

```
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath
    ("~/Views/*/_WebPage.cshtml"))){

    <!-- do something -->

    }
```

How do I define a unknown folder name in the directory?

There are multiple folders in Views directory containing the same file called _WebPage.cshtml.

Comment: you simply go up one level

Comment: you can't define something that is unknown - but maybe I've misunderstood the question...

Comment: maybe give us some context on what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: there are multiple folders in Views directory containing the same file. I tried to use asterisk to define the folders, but it isn't working for me. "~/Views/*/_WebPage.cshtml"

Comment: "...isn't working for me..." - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: the path isn't able to locate the file called _WebPage.cshtml, if I use asterisk to  define the folder

Comment: i would view the folder structure as a tree - do a search around for code making a recursive call in directories/sub-directories - this way you will find the thing you need.